# Given a large amount of data, find the most common queries

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nlp, data-mining

Problem: I have a large CSV with several columns and tens of millions of rows. One of these columns have a query variable that stores plaintext. I need to find the most common queries across the data, but because these are user generated queries, I need to have queries like

> help with installing [x product]

and

> [x product] help installing

contribute to the same query for summary/reporting sake.

I have already pruned the data of all common words and other JSON wrapping, etc.

You can assume that the values of each row contains only important words to the query the user made, and that I need to retrieve the most common queries made.

I understand that it's impossible to provide code for a high level question like this, but I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction - if only even keywords to search in Google to begin my search/understanding of this problem space, or some research paper or blog post that addresses the problem I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly have an interesting problem on your hands.  I'll throw out some (hopefully) useful tools for you to throw at it.

The first thing you will likely want to do is apply a [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm to correct possible misspellings in the queries.  This is part of the data clean up process you'll want to do before your main algorithm does it's thing.

The second thing you'll want to do is apply a stemming algorithm to each query.  Stemming involves returning simply the *root* of the word.  Some examples:

```
jumping  -> jump
jumps    -> jump
jumper   -> jump
```

This way you are normalizing all of the important keywords in your queries.

Now you may go for a "more like this" approach for each query to find other queries that are similar to it, then batch them together.  So how does "more like this" work?

It involves three components: TF, IDF and field length.  TF is *Term Frequency* - how often each term is in the current query (which boosts its score).  IDF is *Inverse Document Frequency* - how often a term is in ALL of the queries (which sinks its score).  And field length is simply how long the query field (the shorter the more boost to the score).  Let me expand a bit:

You want to compare `help instaling [product x]` to other records.

The first order of business is to correct misspellings across all of your queries:

```
help installing [product x]
```

Next, stem the queries:

```
help install [product x]
```

Next, you will choose one query and begin comparing it to all the other queries (or at least all of the other queries that have not already been matched together as similar to other queries that you've already processed).  We'll start with the query above.

Let's create a *term vector*

```
help (1)
install (1)
[x] (1)
```

Each of these terms only appear once.  That's the Term Frequency for the current query.  Let's compare the IDF of each of these terms.  Turns out `help` comes up 15,000 times across all of the queries, `install` comes up `2,000` times, and `[product x]` comes up `500` times.  This means `help` is the LEAST relevant because it appears so often, and `[product x]` is the MOST relevant because it appears rarely.  Get it?

And the field length works to finding a score like this: the longer the query, the lower it's score.  Why?  Because if a query of only 20 characters matches your terms, it is far more likely to be an exact duplicate than a query of 1,000 characters where the user is rambling and talking about many different topics.  See?

Now you can learn more about [TF/IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) to figure out a good implementation.

But I have some good news for you.  All of this work has been done for you in the [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) library.  Using Lucene you can index each of your queries as a document.  Lucene will apply the *stemming* automatically for you when indexing it.  Furthermore, Lucene has a "more like this" algorithm that uses TF/IDF for you.  And, finally, Lucene can apply fuzzy matching using the Levenshtein distance calculator for each of your queries, too.  Awesome!!  If you find working with Lucene to be a little too close to the "bare metal", you can also use [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html) which is an advanced high-level wrapper around Lucene.  It really kicks butt.

Please note, I am not an expert in these topics.  However, I hope this gives some ideas.  Cheers!

http://cephas.net/blog/2008/03/30/how-morelikethis-works-in-lucene/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Awesome thank you so much. To summarize, there is still some more preprocessing I have to do (misspellings, stemming/lemmatization), and then I should look into TF-IDF to create things that are "more like" and other grouping algorithms. Something else I discovered while during more research is n-grams, and I think that will be fairly useful for this purpose as well. I'll be using the Spark library, and while it doesn't have NLP integration, it does do a lot of the TF-IDF stuff and other feature extraction.